# Can't get the latest posts from an RSS feed with zRSSfeed plugin

Tags: rss, feed, blogger

I have included this RSS feed:
http://veronicalercari.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

in this page: http://verler.com/blog.html using the zRSSfeed plugin.

The issue is it isn't bringing the latest posts. The last one it shows is from 2 months ago.

Comment: Does this happen with every feed or just this one? What have you tried to do to troubleshoot so far?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be a browser caching issue, I have accessed the page from lots of different browsers and everywhere I get the same outdated feed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the Google Feed API and your feed. We have the feed working correctly by using an additional option in the Google Feed API that is meant for historical records - this is a little odd and needs further looking into, however does seem to work.

The lastest version of zRSSFeed (1.1.8) now includes an 'historical' option. By setting this to 'true' will show all your latest records.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#test').rssfeed('http://veronicalercari.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default',{
          historical: true
     });
});
```

http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/